# Heat Transfer Problem - Cooling of water through aluminium coil

Tags: heat-transfer, thermal-conduction, heat

I am trying to figure out how to compute the outlet temperature of water that goes through a coil and is cooled down by an aluminium block. The goal of this system is to cool down the water, by approximately 15 degrees (from ambiant temperature to around 10 degrees C). The image below is a visualization of the problem:

[image: Visualization of the problem]

The figures shows the aluminium coil (in grey), the foam (in yellow) and the aluminium block (in metallic) which is basically a dense cube which contains the coil. The aluminium coil (grey) is completely casted in an aluminium block (so the coil is totally surrounded by aluminium) and is isolated by PU foam. The insulation is made of a layer of PU foam, with a thermal conductivity of $0.03 \ W/(K \cdot m))$.

Water flows through the aluminium (grey) coil between the inlet (blue tube on the right), and the outlet (blue tube on the left), that has a total length of 10 meters and has a diameter of 1.5cm. The flow rate of the water is 1L/min. The inlet temperature of the water is 25 degrees C. The aluminium block is 20x20x20cm, and has an initial temperature of 5 degrees C. While the water flows through it, the aluminium block increases in temperature. Its final temperature is also unknown.
I want to look at the case in which we have 500ml of water flowing through the coils. The copper tube in bronze contains a refrigerant flow that allows to cool down the block, but we can consider it does not cool down the block during this problem (so it cooled down the block to 5 degrees C only and that's it).

Basically we know that the heat that is transferred from the water to the aluminium block should correspond to the increase in temperature of the aluminium block, so we have:
The heat transferred by the water:
$\dot Q = \dot m \cdot C_p \cdot (T_{inlet} - T_{water  \ outlet}) = 4180 \ J/(kg \cdot K) \cdot 0.017 \ kg/s \cdot (25 \ K - T_{water \ outlet})$

The heat gained by the aluminium block:
$\dot Q =  m \cdot C_p \cdot (T_{end} - T_{start}) \cdot \dfrac{1}{\Delta t} = 2.7 \ kg \cdot 910 \ J/(kg \cdot K) \cdot (T_{end} - 5 \ K) \cdot \dfrac{1}{\Delta t},$

where $\Delta t$ takes into account the fact that the longer the water takes to go through the coil, the more the water is cooled down by the aluminium block. So the longer the coil is, or the lower the flow rate is, the more the water will cool down. I am not sure how this should be translated in the formula, hence why I added a simple $\Delta t$.

Since I have two unknowns and one combined equation, I need other equations to find the final temperature of the water (that is mostly what I am looking for) and hence the final temperature of the aluminium block. Obviously, I need to take into account the heat transfer between the aluminium block and the aluminium coil, as well as the heat transfer between the coil and the water that flows through it.

Does anyone have some tips on how to proceed ? It can also be a reasonable approximation. Any help is welcome!

Thanks a lot!

Johmi

EDIT: Made a few modifications regarding the numbers:

- Diameter of coil is 1.5cm and not 2cm
- Dimensions of the aluminium block are 20x20x20cm and not 15x15x15cm
- The insulation is made of a layer of PU foam, with a thermal conductivity of $0.03 \ W/(K \cdot m))$
- We look at the case in which 500ml of water flows through the coils

Comment: One problem - if your pipe is 10m at 2cm dia. you don't have any room for a block - almost all that volume is pipe. You have 22 coils of pipe 15cm diameter - that's 44cm high.

Comment: If there are no losses to the surroundings, how could the heat lost by the water be different than the heat gained by the aluminum?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Unless the aluminum block is cooled it will soon be 25C.  Your dimensions don’t work, compare volume of the pipe to volume of the block.   You have a bunch of numbers that just don't make sense.

Comment: My question wasn't really about the numbers but more the methods, hence I added some numbers that represent this problem. I relooked at it and modified my initial post: the volume of the block is 20x20x20cm and not 15x15x15cm, I added that the insulation layer is PU foam with a thermal conductivity of $0.03\  W/(K \cdot m)$. The 8-9 coils depicted in this figure have a diameter of 1.5cm instead of 2cm. Hence they fit in the aluminium block. My main question is: If we consider the case in which we have 500ml of water flowing through the coils, how to compute the outlet temperature of the water?

Comment: I suggest you use a much smaller diameter pipe, maybe 0.5cm internal diameter. You want the water to have as much contact with the sides of the pipe as possible and to be flowing as quickly as possible for most efficient heat transfer. Then you can also use a smaller block. You will need at least 3kg aluminum. (The first water that comes out will be close to 5C so the last can be close to 15C to average 10C.)